# how to calculate sum of list values in single column in Tableau

Tags: nsmutableurlrequest, tableau-api

I have to calculate sum of  CCA + Exgratia + Gratuity+ HRA + LTA + Medical

but these values are stores in single column "Allow amt"  for all Employees

and Allow Desc contains  CCA , Exgratia , etc,..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwAEt.png

Comment: show sample data,how can anyone know what are you trying to do?

Comment: Here is the my sample data      https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwAEt.png

Answer (score 0):

one way is to take the row sum by going to `Analysis` menu and 'Totals -> Show row grand total'. One more way is to take sum of the values in another sheet and combine those in a dashboard.